# Evaluate the integral of primitive $\frac{1}{x(x+2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am doing this integral by example:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x(x+2)}\ dx.$$

The example in the book, starts with $\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)} \leq \dfrac{1}{x^2}.$

Why is this important? Why does the example in the book start like that?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe just to show convergence... do partial fractions.

Comment: what do you want to do? Prove convergence or find an antiderivative?

Comment: I want to solve a integral solve the integral

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{x(x+2)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+2}$ (This is partial fractions). After solving for $A$ and $B$ and splitting up the fraction as shown, the integral becomes easy to evaluate.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt what about the borders, because the function breaks at x=2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)}\leq\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, then 
$$\int^\infty_1\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)}dx\leq\int^\infty_1\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=\left.-\dfrac{1}{x}\right|^\infty_1=1$$
i.e. $\displaystyle\int^\infty_1\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)}dx\leq1$. This shows convergence of the integral.

Now, split $\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)}$ as a partial fraction:
$$\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)}=\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x+2}=\dfrac{(A+B)x+2A}{x(x+2)}\\
\implies (A+B)x+2A=1.$$
Solve for $A$ and $B$, then substitute them into $\dfrac{1}{x(x+2)}=\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x+2}$, and integrate it term by term.

Comment: I hope you don't mind with my editing. +1.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thanks for the edit!